# Is DefaultAWSCredentialsProviderChain (v1.11.124) thread-safe

Tags: java, amazon-web-services, thread-safety, aws-sdk

Neither [AWSCredentialsProviderChain.java](https://github.com/aws/aws-sdk-java/blob/master/aws-java-sdk-core/src/main/java/com/amazonaws/auth/AWSCredentialsProviderChain.java) nor [DefaultAWSCredentialsProviderChain](https://github.com/aws/aws-sdk-java/blob/master/aws-java-sdk-core/src/main/java/com/amazonaws/auth/DefaultAWSCredentialsProviderChain.java) state that they are thread-safe in their documentation. 
Are they thread-safe in the linked implementation (as of version 1.11.124)?

If so, then I think we can assume that the underlying providers in the chain are as well (i.e. whether ProfileCredentialsProvider is thread-safe)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

All credential providers provided within the AWS SDK are thread-safe, including the default credential chain and the ones to which it delegates.

Using the mutation methods on the credential providers (eg. the credential provider chain's `setReuseLastProvider`) do not always act on volatile variables, so it is encouraged to fully configure the credential provider before using it from multiple threads.

Comment: Right, right. Thanks @millems. Could you clarify what you mean by " fully configure"?
Kevin Mullin pointed out to me that if `getCredentials()` is called again before this line: https://github.com/aws/aws-sdk-java/blob/master/aws-java-sdk-core/src/main/java/com/amazonaws/auth/AWSCredentialsProviderChain.java#L121, then the code may iterate through the whole chain again.

Comment: It is best to call any `set*` methods on the provider before you start to use it. 'lastUsedProvider' is fairly unpredictable because the field isn't volatile, so a thread may cache its value thread-locally, and there's no locking around it. The `lastUsedProvider` is a best-effort field, so the whole chain could be iterated multiple times. It would be relatively inefficient to prevent this, and the cost of traversing the chain multiple times is not excessive.

Answer (score 0):

If you are creating a small number of instances, it is best to create separate instances. If you are truly creating a large enough number of instances for the overhead to matter, the calls to `getCredentials()` is arguably thread-safe, but the caching of which provider to use may be "less efficient". Take a look at https://github.com/aws/aws-sdk-java/blob/master/aws-java-sdk-core/src/main/java/com/amazonaws/auth/AWSCredentialsProviderChain.java#L121